# Is it possible to solve this problem with linear programming?

Tags: python, math, mathematical-optimization, linear-programming

I have the following set of linear equations and constraints:

- N * x
- Coefficient matrix N has a dimension of 31x33 (33 variables and 31 equations)
- Array x has a dimension of 33x1 (33 variables)
- The product N * x is either greater than or equal to (>=) or less than or equal to (<=) the array D with a dimension of 31x1. This depends on the corresponding entry on another boolean array F (True/False) with the same dimension 31x1. Both D and F are known.
- The lower and upper limits for unknown variables x are known. For some variables x is set to a specific integer value (no range).

Given this set of linear equations and contraints I need to find the minimum/maximum value of all unknown variables in x that satisfy the given constraints. So I am looking for 33 solutions where on each one only a single variable is maximised or minimised.

Also, is it possible to somehow quantify how constrained the overall solution space becomes with these x_min and x_max values (for example for a certain x_i=x_min there needs to be a range of solutions for other x,c with c is not equal to i)?

What would be the best way to approach this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is definitely a textbook example of a linear-programming problem. What made you doubt this? Keep in mind that `F` is redundant - the "correct" approach would be to multiply the corresponding rows by `-1`, so your matrix stays consistent.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure what exactly is your objective. Are you looking to find a single solution which maximizes the sum of all variables, or are you looking for 33 solutions where each of those maximizes one of those variables? Both are, of course, LP problems, not sure which one are we solving.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Sorry for being not 100% clear. I am looking for 33 solutions where on each one a variable is maximized (or minimized so to speak).

Comment: Yeah, well, that was just a note for you that you need to realize this. Good! Well, now you can just... go ahead and do it! If you're unable to find a LP library to do it for you, you can always fall back to some sort of a polygon library, since your problem is very simple (you don't pass your variables into a function to optimize, you just optimize the variables straight up) and if you had the full polygon, you'd knew the entire constraints of your space. Then, you just find the smallest and largest coordinate of `x[i]` in your polygon and you have your solution.

Comment: The task usually is coined **Optimization-based Bound Tightening** (and is a very common component of some solvers; especially *global nonlinear ones*). So yes, having some LP with `n` variables, solving it `2n` times where each solve has a different objective (e.g. n minimizations; n maximizations) is rather common and usually you would setup the (constraint-)model once and then solve it 2n times with a mutated objective each time. Doing this in a clever way (following some solver API), the solver will be able to *warm-start* each iteration (primal feasibility is kept).